# ASP.NET Timer Control Does not work

Tags: asp.net, timer, asp.net-ajax

I have a timer control in my ASP.NET page i tried to put it into a UpdatePanel but result is still same. With below code tick event doesn't fire. And even doesn't postback the page.

```
<ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"/>
        <asp:Timer ID="tmrUpdateLocations" runat="server" OnTick="tmrUpdateLocations_Tick" Interval="1000"></asp:Timer>
         <div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:500px"></div>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text="!!!"></asp:Label>
```

CodeBehind :

```
 protected void tmrUpdateLocations_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lbl.Text = "TRYING!!";
        }
```

And by the way timer is enabled.
Here is the web.config :

```
<pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajax" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
```

And of course i added AjaxControlToolkit from Nuget Package Manager..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found the answer. I don't know exactly how but it started to work. But i think it's about web.config file. I added httphandler tags and its OK now.

Answer (score 1):

```
<httpHandlers>
<remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>

<httpModules>
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    </httpModules>
</httpHandlers>
```

Add the above  code with in the System.Web element.
Code works fine..

Answer (score 0):

Except correct web form and source code, it's important to fill config file with web extension stuff. All the settings can be found on the [official page](http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/ConfiguringASPNETAJAX.aspx).